# JSON repsonse encoding problems

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I have `ASIHTTPRequest` with JSON response. I use `SBJsonParser` for JSON parsing, I need parse some strings from response. But I have problem with Russian symbols, I receive russian strings like:`–†–Њ—Б—Б–Є—П`

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you use the same encoding on client and server.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) and Apple's NSJSONSerializer. Even the developer of ASIHTTPRequest does not longer recommend using this framework. There's great support for encoding issues in AFNetworking, and it's widely used so I'm pretty sure your bug doesn't exist there.